# Changing background color with time interval

Tags: javascript, timer, background-color, intervals

I was attempting to slowly change my background color from black `rgb(0,0,0)` to `rgb(8,8,8)` and so on onto `rgb(255,255,255)`. I wanted to do this using Javascript and functions. I seem to be getting stuck in an infinite loop and I'm not sure why. Help please. Thank you!

```
<body onload="setInterval">
    <div id="topBanner">
        <h1>Testing</h1>
    </div>
    <script>
        setInterval(function() {
            for (var x = 0; x <= 255; x + 8) {
                document.body.style.background = "rgb(" + x + "," + x + "," + x + ")"
            }
        }, 1000)
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You should take a look at [CSS animations](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/) or [transitions](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/) for this type of effect!

Answer (score 1):

It's because the for loop increment statement `x + 8`:

```
for (var x = 0; x <= 255; x + 8) {
```

You should use either `x = x + 8` or `x += 8` because you're incrementing `x` by 8, but you're not assigning it to `x` again.

Answer (score 0):

Repeatedly changing the page's styles in a `for` loop won't make the appearance change "slowly." That's not to say that the loop will run too fast. Rather, the browser doesn't redraw the page while the script runs.

Instead, set an interval with a function that sets the background to a slightly different color each time and returns immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Casey Chu, you probably want to look into CSS transitions, but if you're looking for something in the neighborhood of your JS:

```
(function ($, interval_ms) {

    var octet = 0;

    var handle = setInterval(function () {

        octet += 8;

        if (octet > 255) {
            clearInterval(handle);
        }

        $('body').css("background-color", "rgb(" + octet + ", " + octet + ", " + octet + ")");


    }, interval_ms);
})(jQuery, 100);
```

`interval_ms` is measured in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="main_div">
      <table id="table_box">
        <tr>
          <td>101</td>
          <td>102</td>
          <td>103</td>
          <td>104</td>
          <td>105</td>
          <td>106</td>
          <td>107</td>
          <td>108</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>109</td>
          <td>110</td>
          <td>111</td>
          <td>112</td>
          <td>113</td>
          <td>114</td>
          <td>115</td>
          <td>116</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>117</td>
          <td>118</td>
          <td>119</td>
          <td>120</td>
          <td>121</td>
          <td>122</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>124</td>
      </table>
    </div>

< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    var def_table = $('#table_box'),
      arr_td,
      tr_len = $(def_table).find('tr').length,
      arr_tr = $(def_table).find('tr'),
      rows = 0,
      cols = 0,
      colorIndex = 0,
      color = ['red', 'orange', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black', 'green'];

    setInterval(function() {
      arr_td_len = $(arr_tr[rows]).find('td').length,
        arr_td = $(arr_tr[rows]).find('td'); //find row tr td 
      $(arr_td[cols]).css('color', 'white');
      $(arr_td[cols]).css('background-color', color[colorIndex]);
      cols++;
      if (cols == arr_td_len) {
        rows++;
        cols = 0;
        if (rows == tr_len) {
          rows = 0;
          colorIndex++;
          if (colorIndex == 6) {
            colorIndex = 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }, 100);
  });

< /script>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/y11LLaea/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick function for a random color, you can alter it to use the colors you want

```
function BgColorTransition(element)
{
   var intervals = setInterval(setBgColor, x-amount-of-seconds);

   function setBgColor()
   {
      var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * (111111 + 999999) - 111111);
      $(element).css({
        backgroundColor: '#'+ran,
        transition: '20s ease-in-out'
     });
   }

}
BgColorTransition('body');
```